# CakePHP with Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, stored-procedures

I am trying to create stored procedure in Cakephp. I have created Procedure in MYSQL and created global function in AppModel.php to hit procedure. The function in AppModel is sProcedure. Now I have 2 conditions I might have variable to return from procedure or may have direct resultset eg. I have created for Pagination. Though its shooting my procedure but not return any result. Is my function require modification?

```
    public function sProcedure($name = NULL, $inputParameter = array(), $outputParameter = array()) {
        $this->begin();
        $parameter = "";
        $outputParam = "";
        foreach ($inputParameter as $params) {
            $parameter .= $parameter == "" ? " '$params' " : ", '$params' ";
        }

        if (count($outputParameter) > 0) {
            foreach ($outputParameter as $prm) {
                $outputParam .= $outputParam == "" ? " @$prm " : ", @$prm ";
            }
        }
        $parameter = ($outputParam) ? $parameter . ", " . $outputParam : $parameter;
        $this->query("CALL `$name`($parameter);");
        $result = $this->query("SELECT $outputParam");
        $this->commit();
        return $result;
    }

    $sel_data = $this->ArticleNews->sProcedure("update_blank", $input_prameter, $output);
    debug($sel_data);
```

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: I am not getting error, My procedure executes as well. But I wish to know how to take output from procedure. Using same function. No matter if I have output resultset or variables.

Comment: @Sankalp is the procedure returning legit values when called directly from MySQL (not using PHP)? Also, $this->query executes the query string passed and returns (if not failing) a resource that should be iterated over.

Comment: Yes its returning correct values. Issues is sometimes I return dataset from SQL like in Pagnation. in that case Do I need to mention column name or simply `SELECT *` in procedure. How to read response in that case. In that scenerio I won't mention output variables. But If I need specific column like count or any other function I would mention output varibles. Would it work with both. Is it require moderation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Breaking down the snippet

```
$this->query("CALL `$name`($parameter);");
```

calls stored procedure. Lets assume that the procedure's body is a simple `SELECT`

```
SELECT table.* FROM table;
```

This procedure returns  a result set. Take a quick look at the code you provided

```
 $this->query("CALL `$name`($parameter);");
```

**Yes**, the procedure is called but the result/[resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) is not assigned to a variable to [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) over.

```
$proc_result = $this->query("CALL `$name`($parameter);");

$proc_data = array();

if (false !== $proc_result)
{
    while ($proc_row = mysqli_fetch_array($proc_result))
    {
        $proc_data[] = $proc_row; 
    }
}

if (!empty($proc_data))
{
    //do whatever with procedure data
}
```

Related documentation: [connector-cpp-tutorials-stored-routines-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-tutorials-stored-routines-statements.html)

Comment: Hi you have taken the first scenario, Case when I don't have output variables, means I have simple SELECT recordset Query. My doubt with this, Is `mysqli_fetch_array` follows standard of CakePHP framework that I am working, I wish to follow standard of Framework as well. 

Case II: I have selected vars for the result. I would put query this way.

$proc_result = $this->query("CALL `$name`($parameter);");
if($outputParam) {
   $result = $this->query("SELECT $outputParam");
} else {
   while ($proc_row = mysqli_fetch_array($proc_result))  {
        $proc_data[] = $proc_row; 
    }
}

Correct ??

Comment: Well, CakePHP is a framework - something that is built upon an existing piece of code. It does not mean that it will cover up all aspects of the fundamental code that is PHP. What I want to say is - you will have to write something in 'pure' PHP as the framework might not provide such functionality.  TLDR; here is a nice artice from CakePHP docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html. However, it is totally correct to use non-framework methods. :)

Comment: Please check my code I have attached for final test case.

Answer (score 4):

Use following code **to call stored procedure cakephp 3**

Its working for me.....

```
$this->connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$meritlists = $this->connection->execute("CALL generateMeritList()")->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys DONT bash your heads

check those couple of lines:

```
$sql="CALL `delete_category`(".$id.");";
$db3= ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db3->query($sql);
```

guaranteed to work. 
the getDatasource returns an $mysqli object so u can use it

check the PHP manual for sp [Calling a stored procedure in php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)